# How to import and use zone.js in Angular 2+ and ES2015 Modules

Tags: javascript, angular, zone.js

How can I work with pure `zone.js` API (like `Zone.current` or creating new zones by forking) in Angular 2+ & ES2015 Modules? When I do:

```
import { Zone } from 'zone.js';
```

I get this error:

```
file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/InTheZone/src/main.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'File 'c:/Users/InTheZone/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts' is not a module.'
at: '3,22'
source: 'ts'
code: '2306'
```

Typings file is there, but it does no export anything.

Comment: Zone is a polyfill for a proposal, not a library. It is avaliable as Zone global. It's supposed to be used in Angular via NgZone provider,

Comment: NgZone does not have API to fork a new zone. Let me rephrase, how can I access Zone global with type information so that typescript compiler is happy?

Comment: With `Zone` global. You should already have `zone.js` imported along with other polyfills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use Zone in angular project to access Zone native API, you can do like this.

```
declare let Zone: any;

class AppComponent {
  method() {
    Zone.current.fork({
      name: 'myZone'
    }).run(() => {
      console.log('in myzone? ', Zone.current.name);
    });
  }
}
```